# отсутствующий операнд в батнике cmd

Tags: cmd, bat, exe

Когда я через командую строку запускаю батник[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  и начинаю выполнение программы, мне пишет "отсут операнд", но файл создает, только в него ничего не записывает.
Когда я в этом же окне второй раз вызываю батник, то у меня сообщения об отсутствующем операнде не выводится и так же создается пустой файл.
Когда я в третий  раз запускаю батник, то только тогда я получаю нужное значение записанное в файл.

не знаю где ошибка.

полный код прилагается:

```
    @echo of
chcp 1251
echo. "Введите абсолютный путь к папкe:"
set /p n="путь: " 
IF NOT EXIST %n% (
  echo "Данной папки нет"
  ) ELSE (
  cd %n%
  for  /R %%e in (*) do set /a cnt+=1 
  for /f "usebackq delims='\n'" %%l in (`tasklist`) do set /a tc+=1 
  set /A v=%tc%*%cnt%  
  echo. %v%>%time:~6,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~0,2%.txt
 )
pause
```

Comment: Советую прочитать про отложенное раскрытие переменных в CMD.

Comment: "Отсутствующий операнд" появляется после операции **set /A v=%tc%*%cnt%**.Это значит, что одна из множителей-переменных не инициализирована, то есть пуста. Это или **tc** или **cnt**.